# How Do I Disable Unwanted Requests? (MySQL, .htaccess, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To start, I am a beginner with PHP and .htaccess.  Here is my dilemma...

I have built dynamic pages and used htaccess to rewrite the urls. There are 3 types of pages... Examples:

> State: example.com/massachusetts-colleges.html
>
> City: example.com/massachusetts-colleges/boston-ma-colleges.html
>
> College: example.com/massachusetts-colleges/boston-ma-colleges/harvard.html

The problem is that pages are being requested (from old linking structure probably) that shouldn't exist such as:

> example.com/boston-ma-colleges.html

The state urls are stored in a locations table in the database (stateSlug = massachusetts-colleges).  The city urls are also stored in the locations table in the database and the corresponding state slug is also stored with that city (citySlug = boston-ma-colleges and stateSlug = massachusetts-colleges).  The Colleges are stored in a different table and use ID's to correspond with the cities.

How can I use .htaccess to prevent any "OTHER" urls from being accessible (page displays template and no data), and show a 404 page (or redirect to home page)?

This is what my .htaccess file looks like now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/statePage.php?stateSlug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-colleges/([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/cityPage.php?citySlug=$2&stateSlug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-colleges/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)\.html?$ php/collegePage.php?collegeSlug=$3&citySlug=$2&stateSlug=$1 [L]
```

Again, I am somewhat new to the htaccess and php languages.  I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, but replace `index.php` with your 404 page:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$l [L]
```

This should redirect all file and directory requests that were not found to `index.php` or your choice of script file, a 404 page for example. Just remember to set the headers to a 404 response code.

I got this from the CodeIgniter wiki page at http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Their wiki page was very helpful when I tried to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your content is matched by one of the above URLs, you can simply forbid access to everything else by adding another rule to the end:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

To avoid messing with requests your images and CSS, you should add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

If you have directories which should be made inaccessible, place a .htaccess in them with only the following:

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Comment: I just tried adding what you told me and it caused a "Forbidden" on the pages that are supposed to show up...

Answer (score 0):

rewrite all your public files to fake directory `/allow/..`, display `404` for any request which is not in `/allow/..` directory. Finally rewrite files from `/allow/..` to real directory.

It's great workaround IMO :) Better than using `deny all` in every dir...

Comment: Thanks... I ended up figuring something out that wasn't in htaccess... I used the page code to check for the slug in the db and change the header to a 404 if it's not there.